# tkinter multiple classes and global variables

Tags: python, tkinter

Pretty new to python and I am currently trying to make my first GUI app with TKinter. The app prompts the user to select an option from 4 drop down widgets and select submit, this will export an excel spreadsheet(still to implement).

I got the GUI working on it's own, but i am having trouble using a global variable which I need to use between classes.

Currently when I run the code I get the error " **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'submissions' ". 
I have tried entering 'submissions' like so 'main_window = open_mainprogram(root, submissions)' but this produces the error: "name 'submissions' is not defined".

Below is the main class for my GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from global_stuff import *


#submissions = []

class open_mainprogram(global_stuff):

    #submissions = []

    def __init__(self, master, submissions):
        #define main window#
        self.master = master
        master.title("Easier checking")
        master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
        master.maxsize(width=800, height=800)

        #Program Description#
        self.program_description= Label(self.master, text =("This program is to speed up the checking process by automating the filling in of the check list."))
        self.program_description.grid(columnspan = 10)

        #Label drop down menu week 1#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text = ("|Week One Checks:|"))
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        #Create drop down menu week 1#
        self.check_progressone = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressone.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionone = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressone, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionone.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        #week 2#
        #Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text = ("|Week Two Checks:|"))
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        #Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progresstwo = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progresstwo.set("Pending")
        self.select_optiontwo = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progresstwo, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optiontwo.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

        #week 3#
        #Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text = ("|Week Three Checks:|"))
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row = 2, column = 5)

        #Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progressthree = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressthree.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionthree = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressthree, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionthree.grid(row = 3, column = 5)

        #week 4#
        #Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text = ("|Week Four Checks:|"))
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row = 2, column = 7)

        #Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progressfour = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressfour.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionfour = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressfour, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionfour.grid(row = 3, column = 7)

        #submit button#
        def submitted(self, submissions):
            submitted_first = self.check_progressone.get()
            submitted_second = self.check_progresstwo.get()
            submitted_third = self.check_progressthree.get()
            submitted_fourth = self.check_progressfour.get()
            #global submissions
            submissions = submitted_first + submitted_second + submitted_third + submitted_fourth
            print (submissions)
            return (submissions)


        self.submit_button = Button(master, text = "Submit", command = submitted)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        #Exit button#
        self.exit_button = Button(master, text = "Exit", command = (master.destroy))
        self.exit_button.grid(row = 5, column = 8)

        return (submissions)


root = Tk()
main_window = open_mainprogram(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And Below is my global variables class:

```
class global_stuff:

    submissions = []
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:
If i change the below:

```
main_window = open_mainprogram(root)
```

To then be:

```
main_window = open_mainprogram(root, global_stuff)
```

I receive the error "**init**() should return None, not 'type'"

Comment: Try using 'self' in front of submissions and see, (Just an idea)

Comment: That gives the error "name 'self' is not defined" unfortunately

Comment: I think I have a solution if you are trying to save the `submissions` as `global` to use it later. Am I right?

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad I have created the variable `submissions` in another class to then be able to use it across multiple classes

Comment: Your `__init__` shouldn't return anything. Why does it return `submissions`??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I told it to return `submissions` so that the changes in the function could be used outside this class. Would that still work without returning `submissions` so long as I refer any other class back to the class `open_mainprogram`?

Comment: @FraserClark So you mean in this code that you posted you are trying to update the variable `submission`, That already exists somewhere in another class, Am I right?

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad yes that's correct, that's what `class global_stuff:` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
from tkinter import *


class global_stuff:

    submissions = []

    def test(self):

        print(self.submissions)


class TestClass(global_stuff):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test()


class open_mainprogram(global_stuff):

    def __init__(self, master):
        # define main window#
        self.master = master
        master.title("Easier checking")
        master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
        master.maxsize(width=800, height=800)

        # Program Description#
        self.program_description = Label(self.master,
                                         text="This program is to speed up the checking process by automating the "
                                              "filling in of the check list.")
        self.program_description.grid(columnspan=10)

        # Label drop down menu week 1#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text="|Week One Checks:|")
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # Create drop down menu week 1#
        self.check_progressone = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressone.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionone = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressone, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionone.grid(row=3, column=1)

        # week 2#
        # Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text="|Week Two Checks:|")
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row=2, column=3)

        # Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progresstwo = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progresstwo.set("Pending")
        self.select_optiontwo = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progresstwo, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optiontwo.grid(row=3, column=3)

        # week 3#
        # Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text="|Week Three Checks:|")
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row=2, column=5)

        # Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progressthree = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressthree.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionthree = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressthree, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionthree.grid(row=3, column=5)

        # week 4#
        # Label drop down menu#
        self.week_onelabel = Label(self.master, text="|Week Four Checks:|")
        self.week_onelabel.grid(row=2, column=7)

        # Create drop down menu#
        self.check_progressfour = StringVar(self.master)
        self.check_progressfour.set("Pending")
        self.select_optionfour = OptionMenu(self.master, self.check_progressfour, "Pending", "Completed")
        self.select_optionfour.grid(row=3, column=7)

        # submit button#
        def submitted():
            self.test()
            submitted_first = self.check_progressone.get()
            submitted_second = self.check_progresstwo.get()
            submitted_third = self.check_progressthree.get()
            submitted_fourth = self.check_progressfour.get()
            # global submissions
            self.submissions = submitted_first + submitted_second + submitted_third + submitted_fourth
            print(self.submissions)
            self.test()
            return self.submissions

        self.submit_button = Button(master, text="Submit", command=submitted)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=4, column=1)

        # Exit button#
        self.exit_button = Button(master, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=5, column=8)


root = Tk()
main_window = open_mainprogram(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This will solve your issue. I have defined a `test()` function inside the `global_stuff` and have called it on the top and bottom of `submitted()` function to ensure you that the code works, I also have made a `TestClass` to ensure you.

Comment: Thank you, that has worked. So if I want to use submissions in any other class I need to refer to it as `self.submissions` is that correct?

Comment: @FraserClark Yes, you will have to refer to it as `self.submissions`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple. At the very end of your program, you try to create a `main_window`:

```
main_window = open_mainprogram(root)
```

You pass one argument, `root`, to `open_mainprogram`. That is, you're creating an instance of the `open_mainprogram` class (I think it's poorly named - the name implies to me that it's a function, not a class, but that's a side issue). But the `open_mainprogram` class's initialization function requires *two* arguments:

```
def __init__(self, master, submissions):
```

Needless to say, when you try to create your `open_mainprogram` instance, Python complains that you didn't provide one of the necessary arguments, because you're only passing one, when the initialization function requires two.

Comment: So what would I need to pass though '''main_window = open_mainprogram(root)''' ?

Comment: Whatever `submissions` should be. (Though note that this variable doesn't seem to actually be used until you return them again. The `submissions` from your `submitted` function are programmatically unrelated, though you gave it the same name, so it looks like you haven't realized this. This will cause your button to not work, mind you.)

Comment: So what would then make it programmatically related? as I though the line `def submitted(self, submissions):` pulled the `submissions` variable from my global_stuff class?

Comment: @FraserClark no, that defines a function with a completely unrelated argument that happens to have the same name as the argument in `__init__`